# Are there any examples of Bash scripting within the Linux operating system?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I would like to see some examples of Bash shell scripts within the Linux operating system itself.

I am running CentOS 6.4.

Where can I look on the file system to find some bash scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "the Linux operating system itself". If you mean the
kernel, the kernel does not use shell scripts. The kernel is a monolithic binary
written in C plus, optionally, a number of external modules that are loaded
dynamically.

If you mean the entire OS, then scripts abound. On Red Hat-based distros there
are numerous scripts under `/etc/`, `/bin`, and `/usr`. For instance:

- `/etc/rc.sysinit` -- runs at startup, mounts the filesystems and runs the
  services from /etc/init.d appropriate to the runlevel.
- `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` -- directory containing scripts to start and
  stop networking.

Many of the executables in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are shell scripts. You can find
them with a command like:

```sh
file /bin/* /usr/bin/* | grep script
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching within common executable directories for Bash and sh scripts:

```sh
grep '^#!/bin/(ba)?sh$' -ERl {,/usr,/usr/local}/{,s}bin
```

Unfortunately, this also finds very trivial scripts, but they *are* still Bash scripts…

Answer (score 0):

Usually a few of the scripts in /etc/init.d/ are bash.